# A Ridiculous Looking Puzzle

Tags: riddle, visual, knowledge, cryptic-clues

My friend let me borrow his computer for the weekend because he had some files I needed. His computer is password protected and, instead of writing the password down, he gave me a sheet of paper with the following images.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Apparently, these images are clues to the password.

What could it possibly be?

Comment: does the order of the images matter?

Comment: No, the order does not matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is the password:

> Zoolander

Reasoning:

> Mugatu was the inventor of piano key neck tie (in the film)
>  Derek Zoolander couldn't turn left
>  The plot of the film was to kill the Malaysian Prime Minister
>  Ant farm: "What is this, a center for ants?" (Thanks @BusinessCat)
>  Grave with "Google" on it: "eugoogley" (Thanks @robert-fraser)
>  Tom Selleck in Mangum P.I. : The look Zoolander used was 'Magnum'
>  A ferrari:  Another one of his looks
>  The title of the question is from a quote in the film: "Really ridiculously good looking"

Comment: Also the centre for ants

Comment: @BusinessCat Thanks, added that in.

Comment: And the grave could be a"eugoogley".

Comment: It shares quite some things with magnum P.I. 2, including killing an asian diplomat

Comment: @DennisvanGils I think Tom Selleck used to be a model too but not sure how 'strong' that link would be, he's not really known for it. Edit, ahah Magnum!

Comment: @SlashmanX yes, but the image is from Magnum P.I. specifically, not just Tom Selleck

Comment: @DennisvanGils Yep, 'Magnum' is one of his looks, think I've got all the clues now.

Comment: Yes, that is the password! Well done!

Comment: I'm sorry, isn't that really, *really* ridiculously good-looking?

Answer (score 2):

#### Not an answer

The pictures represent :

> - A crow on google's grave
>  - [Tom Selleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Selleck), an American actor and film producer playing in [Magnum P.I.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnum,_P.I.)
>  - [Najib Razak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Najib_Razak) the sixth and current Prime Minister of Malaysia
>  - A ferrari 488
>  - A *no left turn* traffic signs
>  - A piano tie
>  - An ant hill